# Triangle inequality for fraction proof

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> $$ |\frac{e^{ik|x_1-y|}}{4\pi |x_1-y|}-\frac{e^{ik|x_2-y|}}{4\pi |x_2-y|}| \leq \frac{1}{4\pi}|\frac{1}{|x_1-y|}-\frac{1}{|x_2-y|}|+\frac{1}{4\pi |x_1-y|}|e^{ik|x_1-y|}-e^{ik|x_2-y|}|
> $$

I am wondering if anyone could give me a hint about the above inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\frac{1}{4\pi |x_1-y|}=a$, $\frac{1}{4\pi |x_2-y|}=b$, $k |x_1-y| = \phi_a$, $k |x_2-y| = \phi_b$, then the inequality reads

$$
|a e^{i\phi_a} - b e^{i\phi_b}| \leq |a - b |+a|e^{i\phi_a} - e^{i\phi_b}|
$$
Let $x = b/a$ and $\phi = \phi_b - \phi_a$ then equivalently
$$
|1 - x e^{i\phi}| \leq |1 - x |+|1 - e^{i\phi}|
$$
which is
$$
1 + x^2 - 2 x \cos\phi \leq |1 - x |+2 - 2 \cos\phi
$$
For $x < 1$ we have
$$
x +  x^2 - 2 x \cos\phi \leq 2 - 2 \cos\phi
$$
Since $x^2 < x$ it suffices to prove
$$
x (2- 2\cos\phi) \leq 2 - 2 \cos\phi
$$
which is true.

For $x > 1$ we have
$$
x (x - 2 \cos\phi) \leq x - 2 \cos\phi
$$
This is only true for $x - 2 \cos\phi \leq 0$ or, reconstructing the original notation,
$$1 \leq \frac{|x_1-y|}{ |x_2-y|}\leq 2 \cos (k|x_2-y| - k|x_1-y|) $$
Now whether or not this holds depends on $k$, and since nothing was said about $k$, this is as far as we can get. Alternatively, if there is knowledge that $|x_1-y| \leq |x_2-y|$, then the case $x > 1$ never occurs and the inequality is proven.

Comment: Thank you for your explananiton!